# how to make a bootstrap side menu fill height

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

this is my side menu

```html
<template>
  <div class="p-3 text-bg-dark shadow">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <a
        href="#"
        class="
          align-items-center
          text-white text-decoration-none
          dropdown-toggle
        "
        data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
      >
        <strong>profile</strong>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark shadow">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sign out</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <hr />
    <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link active" data-bs-toggle="pill">
          Today's Tasks
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="pill">All Tasks</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="pill">Create Task</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="pill">Edit Task</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
};
</script>
```

this is my main view

```html
<template>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6 bg-danger"><Sidebar /></div>
      <div class="col-6">content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Sidebar from "@/components/SidebarComp.vue";
export default {
  components: {
    Sidebar,
  },
};
</script>
```

this is what i get
[image]

3 problems

1. How can I fill the remaining height
2. Why doesn't it fill the width even though I'm using container-fluid?
3. If I make its position fixed which is what I want since this is a side menu, this happens : [image]

so basically, how can I make a fixed side menu that fills width and the height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go...

Basically, you have two components: sidebar and content. Add class `left-side` to the sidebar and class `right-side` to the content. Set `width: 20vw;` to the sidebar and `width: 80vw;` to the content. Those are relative CSS units. Be careful, using `%` isn't the same as using `vw` and `vh` (read more about it [here](https://css-tricks.com/fun-viewport-units/#aa-what-are-viewport-units)). Sidebar and content together should take up full screen width (`20vw` + `80vw` = `100vw`). But because of `position: absolute;` sidebar and content will overlap, so you need to push content to the right. This is done by setting `left: 20vw;`.

---

Add class `left-side`.

```
<template>
  <div class="p-3 text-bg-dark shadow left-side">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <a
        href="#"
        class="
          align-items-center
          text-white text-decoration-none
          dropdown-toggle
        "
        data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
      >
        <strong>profile</strong>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark shadow">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sign out</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <hr />
    <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link active" data-bs-toggle="pill">
          Today's Tasks
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="pill">All Tasks</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="pill">Create Task</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="pill">Edit Task</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

Add class `right-side`.

```
<template>
  <div class="container-fluid right-side">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6 bg-danger"><Sidebar /></div>
      <div class="col-6">content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Add CSS:

```
.left-side {
     position: absolute;
     width: 20vw;
     height: 100vh;
     left: 0;
}

.right-side {
     position: absolute;
     width: 80vw;
     left: 20vw;
}
```

Comment: it works thanks but, can you explain how it works? (I'm mainly a backend dev so my css knowledge isn't that good)

what is 'left' and what are vw and vh? are they the same as using %?